# Check if array-list contains a certain string and integer

Tags: java

let's say i have this array list

```
List<String> Speach2R = new ArrayList<>();
Speach2R.add(0, "Hello");
Speach2R.add(1, "yes");
Speach2R.add(2, "Hi");
```

and i wanna say

```
if (messages.contains(any of Speach2R strings){
 said = true;
}
```

also i want to find the int of the founded message, like if message "Hi" exists 
int MessageNumber = 2

Comment: `for(String str : Spearch2R)
System.out.printLn(message.contains(str));` only thing missing is the position

Comment: the int of the message is the index, thus you can get the index of an element by calling `Speach2R.indexOf("somestring")`

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What is the type of `messages`?  Is it another `ArrayList<String>` or something different?  If it's another `ArrayList<String>`, you might be able to use the `retainAll` method.

Comment: i want to check if any string from Speach2R exists or found, thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you message is like a sentence, you need to `iterate` over the word of the `List`

```
Set<Integer> indexes = new TreeSet<>();
String message = "Hi, my name is john, and Hello";
for (String word : Speach2R){
    if (message.contains(word)){
        indexes.add(Speach2R.indexOf(word));
    }
}
```

It will iterate over the word of the `List`, and store in a `Set` all the indexes of the word it founds

---

```
System.out.println("Your message contains :");
for (Integer i : indexes){
    System.out.println(Speach2R.get(i) + ", at index " + i);
}
```

And with that you will print all the words found + their index in the List

Comment: i can't use this method i need check for all of the listed strings not one, hope you can help.

Comment: @KadiemHaider Have you even checked the proposed solution before commenting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ArrayList#contains` method since your List consists of Strings and `ArrayList#indexOf` for the index.

It would look like this

```
String message = "yes";
boolean found = false;
int index = -1;
if(speach2R.contains(message)){
   found = true;
   index = speach2R.indexOf(message);
}
```

Comment: there is a big difference between `speach2R.contains(message)` and `message.contains(speach2R.get(0))`. 1 example wont work if message is `Hi i am fine` where as 2nd example will work if you iterate every element in the list

Comment: @XtremeBaumer OP is searching for a single string.

Comment: he did not state whether the message always contains just 1 word or multiple

Comment: i can't use this method i need check for all of the listed strings not one, hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

With the java 8 Stream API, you can do something like this :

```
messages.stream().filter( Speach2R::contains ).findAny().isPresent()
```

Comment: sorry no idea what you mean by stream api

Comment: It's the new api useful to manipulate collections since java 8. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html